# FM receiver used to control a switch

Tags: switches, wireless, receiver, frequency-modulation

I am new to this and I would like to ask for advice on FM receivers.

I want to create a very low powered (mass produced) item that has a super bright LED, battery and then related circuitry(for FM).

The item must switch on/off the RGB LED (in different states) at different frequencies that are broadcasted from a central FM transmitter.

So, I want to have ten different items (little plastic RGB boxes) that operate at ten different frequencies, so that I can use ten different transmitters to control the ten different items' switches.

Is it possible to send a digital signal (ie on or off) via FM?
Do you think I will be able to make a very small, low powered unit?
Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What kind of range are we talking? Feet? Miles?

Comment: approximately 200-300m (so less than a mile)

Comment: Would it be possible to use two different tones to set the "high" and "low" on the switch? so broadcast at 92Mhz (for argument sake) and then transmit a high pitched sound over the band? Would simple analogue electronics be able to determine the difference between off and on?

Comment: @ReggiePret then use this "less-than-perfect" idea replicated (but with different frequencies) ten times for each receiver module?

Answer (score 1):

A basic on/off signal sent via FM to a receiver is not going to work. You need to encode a data stream with an address (for each receiver) and incorporate a check sum so that the receiving device can check the address, decode "on" or "off" and then double check correct reception with the check sum.

This means incorporating a little MCU in each receiver and having each MCU have its own address (4 bits sounds adequate for your application). If you think you can do it with just individual frequencies and make it robust to interference forget it.

Comment: There is the additional issue that to get range like is wanted the power level of the transmitter gets into regulated territory and the OP cannot freely pick the frequency he wants and remain legal. This means that the OP must work in an available band that is specifically allocated for this type of application. That means that a narrow frequency range is available and thus the need to follow Andy_aka to support all of the devices with address encoding within a single frequency channel.